# QGIS 3 Modeler: Generate New Vector File

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I want my graphical model to create a new **empty** line layer (preferably as a temporary scratch layer) and then add a bunch of new columns to this layer (this part is easy using the field calculator).

I then add new lines manually after the model has run.

Is this possible to do inside the graphical modeler or do I need to manually create the layer beforehand and then specify it as a data input?

(edited for clarity)

Comment: There are several options available. Which have you tried, and how does the outcome (not) satisfy your needs?

Comment: To be honest I haven't found any of the options yet. Could you let me know about one of them?

Comment: Just search for "create" in the toolbox. Maybe also try other terms, which could describe your goal better.

Comment: Sorry, I think my initial question was not clear enough, I edited it to explain my desired result better. I did search for "create" and could not find what I needed.

Comment: There still is `extenttolayer`?